# Negative output from multiple linear regression for precipitation time series

Tags: multiple-regression

i am trying to find missing precipitation from other best correlated stations by using multiple linear regression.
But my regression equation gives negative values (which is not possible for ppt)
So what should I do now?
Plz help
Sample calculation is attached
(same equation is obtained using R, XLSTAT, Excel) (Removing missing observations)[image: MLR for precipitation]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Negative values are permissible in linear regression; the Gaussian distribution permits all possible values. You might consider log-transforming your data, although that will cause you problems with any days that have 0 precipitation, or you could use a distribution and modelling method that doesn't permit non-negative values. I have used a Tweedie distribution for modelling precipitation before, but others distributions are used often too.

Comment: @GavinSimpson: do you want to post your comment(s) as an answer? [Better to have a short answer than no answer at all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) Anyone who has a better answer can post it.

Answer (score 0):

Negative values are permissible in linear regression; the Gaussian distribution permits all possible values. You might consider log-transforming your data, although that will cause you problems with any days that have 0 precipitation, or you could use a distribution and modelling method that doesn't permit non-negative values. I have used a Tweedie distribution for modelling precipitation before, but others distributions are used often too.